# Allocating resources for SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding allocating resources for SQL Server 2008 R2. We have physical server Windows 2008 R2 with three installations of SQL Server 2008 R2 for Production, test and development. The server has 64GB of RAM and 24 cores. If we want to allocate specific amount of resources to specific instance, can we do it? For instance, we want to allocate 32 GB and 12 cores for production instance, and 12 GB and 6 cores each for test and development.

Because all three instances are on the same physical server, we do not want the test and development instances to consume more resources than we want them to. Is there a way to set it in the server or in SQL Server?

Comment: Although it is not always possible but it is best to keep your Development/Testing environment as much as possible identical to the production environment, so when you are developing and testing you get the actual results that you would get in the production environment.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [sf] than here. Check the guidelines for each before posting there, though.